# How to execute a command on a machineA from machineX through a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh, ubuntu-12.04

I have an application server running on Ubuntu 12.04 which I am starting and stopping by below commands -

For stopping the app server

```
david@machineA:/opt/kml$ /opt/kml/bin/kml_start_stop.sh stop
```

For starting the app server

```
david@machineA:/opt/kml$ /opt/kml/bin/kml_start_stop.sh start
```

Now I am trying to write a shell script which will stop and start my application server by using the above command but this shell script I will be running from `machineX`. And from `machineX` we can login passwordless without typing any password for user `david` to `machineA`

For example - From `machineX` I can do `ssh david@machineA` without typing my password.

Below is what I have started. Does everything looks right?

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh david@machineA

/opt/kml/bin/kml_start_stop.sh stop
sleep 10s
/opt/kml/bin/kml_start_stop.sh start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do that because `ssh` will login and wait for commands, whereas you want to feed the commands to the very same ssh.  The script should look more like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read host rest; do
  ssh david@$host <<EOF &
  /opt/kml/bin/kml_start_stop.sh stop
  sleep 10s
  /opt/kml/bin/kml_start_stop.sh start
  EOF
done < hostlist.txt
wait
```

That uses a Bash feature called a "here document" which feeds the text to the stdin of the `ssh` process.

Edit: I added a small trick: I background each of the ssh jobs as they are started, because each one will take some time to complete (at least 10 seconds due to the sleep).  Then at the end I do `wait` to wait for all of them to complete.  This way, the entire script can run in 10 seconds plus the overhead time, regardless of how many servers there are.

Comment: Thanks a lot John. Even Basile also provided same thing. I am glad I learned one more thing today. One more quick question, suppose I have multiple machine names like `machineA` on which I need to execute `/opt/kml/bin/kml_start_stop.sh stop` and then `/opt/kml/bin/kml_start_stop.sh` start from the same shell script which will be running from `machineX` only. What is the best way to do this? I was thinking to save all the app server machine names in a file and then read that file and execute the command? If possible, can you provide an example for that as well?

Comment: @user2809564: I updated my answer to add a loop like you asked.

Comment: Thanks John, so this `hostList.txt` file will have each line as the machine name right?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) to execute remotely some script:

```
ssh david@machineA << EOJ
  /opt/kml/bin/kml_start_stop.sh stop
  sleep 10
  /opt/kml/bin/kml_start_stop.sh start
EOJ
```

in your case, you could also execute several `ssh` commands and `sleep` locally:

```
ssh david@machineA /opt/kml/bin/kml_start_stop.sh stop
sleep 10
ssh david@machineA /opt/kml/bin/kml_start_stop.sh start
```

BTW, I recommend learning more about shell scripting. You could read [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) (with a critical eye, it does have imperfections) and the [documentation of GNU `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html). In particular, to do that on several machines, you might use some bash  `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot Basile. Learned something new today. One more thing, suppose I have multiple machine names like `machineA` on which I need to execute `/opt/kml/bin/kml_start_stop.sh stop` and then `/opt/kml/bin/kml_start_stop.sh start` from the same shell script which will be running from `machineX` only. What is the best way to do this? I was thinking to save all the app server machine names in a file and then read that file and execute the command?

Comment: In general, I have multiple machines in which app server is running so I need to execute the command on all those app servers from a single shell script running from `machineX`

Answer (score 1):

This script would execute the commands on the remote terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh david@machineA '/opt/kml/bin/kml_start_stop.sh stop && sleep 10s && /opt/kml/bin/kml_start_stop.sh start'
```

In case if you have used the below script then, a separate ssh session shell would be spawned to connect to the remote machine and the below commands would be run on the local machine shell instead on the remote

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh david@machineA 
/opt/kml/bin/kml_start_stop.sh stop
sleep 10s
/opt/kml/bin/kml_start_stop.sh start
```

Comment: This is worse than the other answers here because it opens two separate ssh sessions, each of which may take a significant amount of time to set up on a WAN.